# Apache keeps adding 8080 port by itself while I'm telling it to use 80 only

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, port

Here's my [`httpd.conf`](http://pastebin.com/pSzcLXWH). Inside it, I have the following in place

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
#Listen 127.0.0.1:8887
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
#Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
Listen 192.168.1.4:80
```

and I have a `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wordpress(.*)$ wp-oct/live$1
```

in my local www folder with wordpress installed in `/wp-oct/live/` to which `/wordpress/` is supposed to redirect to, but it doesn't. It instead redirects to [`http://localhost:8080/wp-oct/live/`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mHNJ.png). Why is 8080 showing up?

Comment: Redirect can be cached in browser and is tricky to get rid of... can you test it on different browser/workstation?

Comment: A redirect to port 8080 is no indication that Apache is listening on port 8080.  That `RewriteRule` should not cause a redirect.  There *must* be more to your configuration and I think you'll need to paste some of it here to get a useful answer.  All of your rewrite rules would be a good start.

Comment: @KamilŠrot I've tried all my browsers and their respective incognito modes.

Comment: @Ladadadada Those are the only rules on my `.htaccess` in www root folder. What other confs do you mean?

Comment: [SOLVED] So this was causing it: `ServerName 127.0.0.1:8080` (line224 my [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/pSzcLXWH))

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already solved it, but for anyone who comes across this post, one way to troubleshoot this is to mod_info to pull up the server info page (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html) and then search for 8080 to see where 8080 might be getting defined.